# Searching for multiple strings in AWK

Tags: string, awk

How are you?

I know it's possible to use: `awk '/string/ { print }' filename`.
Is there any thing which allows me to use the same command + multiple strings?
Maybe: `awk '/string1/ /string2/ ... { print }' filename`?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The thing between `/`s in `/string/` isn't a string, it's a regexp. Please clarify if you're trying to search for a regexp or a string and if you want to do partial field, full field, partial line, full line or some other kind of match AND tell us if you want to find lines that contain all of the "strings" or just one of them or something else so we can best help you. Actually - [edit] your question to show concise, testable sample input and expected output that covers all of your use cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes there are of course lot of ways to accomplish "multi strings match", for example (`print` is the default action):

```
$ cat file
string1
string2
string3
string4
$ awk '/string1|string2/' file
string1
string2
$ awk '/string1/ || /string2/' file
string1
string2
$
```

patterns are really flexible, here some documentation from `gawk`: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Pattern-Overview.html

Comment: awk command can be generalized as `$ awk '$1~/string1|string2/ {print}' file`